# Keep a thread alive, after closing (Silverlight)

Tags: multithreading, silverlight, dynamics-crm-2011

I want to know if there is anyway, I can keep a thread alive. I'm calling a CRM 2011 async method, when Application.Current.Exit event occurs. The thing is, the application executes the CRM.ExecuteAsync(request); method, but it exits before CRM.ExecuteCompleted.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you can't outlive the frame allocated to the Silverlight process.

And what happens if the user closes the whole process: be it a browser tab in modern browser (one process per tab) or the whole browser?

Anyway you could try to prevent the closing and request a delay from the user: http://mark.mymonster.nl/2011/01/30/how-to-cancel-the-closing-of-your-silverlight-application-in-browser-and-out-of-browser

But you force some interactivity, that could I guess prevent the correct shutdown of Windows and surprise users.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, I tried this, but the problem is, I'm on a Lync WCE, and it doesn't work (I tried attaching Silverlight to Internet Explorer and worked great). I'm trying to use Thread.Join(); but no luck for now. Any other idea?

Comment: Never worked with Lync, but you may have more chance with the Lync interop API.